# How to run old games installer on Windows 10?

Tags: pc, windows-10

I have a couple of old CD games such as Mig-29 Fulcrum, F-16 Novalogic and F-22 Raptor etc. and I want to install them.
When I load the CD in my laptop it runs and open's up the launcher but when I click the "Install Game" nothing happens.

The setup launcher doesn't launch. Why? 
Is this because it is a 32 bit installer or 16 bit Installer? (I have windows 10 64 bit).
I even manually go to the setup located in the CD and try to run it in compatibility mode, admin Mode etc, but the setup Application doesn't run/open up/start.
How do I make the setup application to run on my laptop?

Comment: The 64-bit version of Windows 10 dropped support the disc based copy protection used in many old games, and that's likely why these installers don't work.

Comment: 32-bit installers are supported by Win10, 16bit installers are not (haven't been since Vista or 7), but you will get an error message, stating that this is a 16 bit application, if that's the case. Without an error message I'd concur with Ross. You might try to install in safe mode, but your best bet would be a VM as the answer states.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/how-to-get-old-16-bit-windows-games-to-work-on-64-bit-windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [interview with Boris Schneider-Johne](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm70oTW-p-s&feature=youtu.be&t=15m30s) from Microsoft explaining why old games won't run on Windows 10.

> “Everything that ran in Windows 7 should also run in Windows 10. There are just two silly exceptions: antivirus software and stuff that’s deeply embedded into the system needs updating – but the developers are on it already – and then there are **old games on CD-Rom that have DRM**. This DRM stuff is also deeply embedded in your system, and that’s where Windows 10 says “sorry, we cannot allow that, because that would be a possible loophole for computer viruses.” That’s why there are a couple of games from 2003-2008 with Securom, etc. that simply don’t run without a no-CD patch or some such. We can just not support that if it’s a possible danger for our users. There are a couple of patches from developers already, and there is stuff like GOG where you’ll find versions of those games that work.” [(translated by Rock, Paper, Shotgun)](https://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2015/08/17/windows-10-safedisc-securom-drm/)

It's hard after that to counter Microsoft in their decision. As he said, you can buy an other digital copy that works on Windows 10, but I know, it's not really nice to buy something we already have. Sadly, this is the easier solution. Steam is selling every games you mentioned in your question. However you can try solutions below, but it requires some specific knowledge and may take time to set up.

The first alternative solution is to [dual boot your computer](http://www.howtogeek.com/214477/how-to-dual-boot-two-or-more-versions-of-windows/) with an older Windows version that can install and run your games. Each time you'll boot your computer, you'll have the choice running Windows 10 (daily usage) or Windows 98 (for games). [Here's a second example setting up dual boot.](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/dual-boot-windows-10-other-versions-windows/)

Finaly, you can try to install a virtual machine with an older Windows version and play the games, but it will not handle your full PC performance and there is risks that may not work correctly.

--EDIT--

As mentioned in comments, if you're able to install the game but unable to launch it, you can apply a no-cd patch.

Comment: Alright thx guys looks like there is not much of choices. I guess i have to eithier buy a digital copy of the games or try the VM PC methods.It's sad that the these games in the steam are 9.99$. And these games don't even ever have any discounts.Anyway thx all.

Comment: Don't forget the dual boot, it will work, but it's a little bit harder to setup !..

Comment: Securom etc. is rarely (read: never) used *for the installer*. The installer must run to install the DRM. I can think of several securom games that I was able to install on Windows 7 that would not run *after install* because of securom (e.g. brothers in arms: road to hill 30). However, there is an exception when they make intentionally-crafted "bad discs", but the symptom for these is that they will not mount (and fallback PIO mode is enabled on the optical drive)

Comment: @LuckyAli  There is a 3rd option, but not one we would condone on this site.  If you search on this topic, you'll find many articles that suggest looking for a "No CD" patch in order to make these games playable again.  That option is honestly the "correct" answer, but it doesn't feel like the best since it's against what I concider to be one of our core rules.

Answer (score -3):

1. Get a Virtual PC software (VM Box and such)
2. Install old windows (whatever worked for you, like XP for instance)
3. Install your game
4. ?????
5. Profit!

Comment: While emulators like DosBox work, a VM for older games tend to run choppy or extremely slow if they use the GPU.  It would be better to just have an older machine, but of course that isn't an option here.

Comment: @NBN-Alex: An emulator is not a VM. That's not a relevant comparison. Modern VM's are in fact capable of virtualizing GPU's.

Comment: True, a friend of mine is playing CS:GO from a MAC trough Virtual Environment ....